# After Filtering Which List Item Selected

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview that displays a list of "Athlete" objects.  When an item in the list is selected, the user is brought to another activity that displays more information about the Athlete and allows edits to the object.  To determine which Athlete was selected, I look at the position in the listView.

There is also the option to filter the listView, which rearranges the items in the list.  At this point, the position of each Athlete on the list no longer matches their original position (which is the value I have stored and use to determine which Athlete was selected) so I have no way of identifying which Athlete has been selected.

How can I determine which Athlete was selected after filtering?

Answer (score 0):

If your Athlete names are unique or has a unique ID then skip the step 1. Else try the following:
Step 1: add a additional textView in the listRow xml. (If you don't want to  make it visible to the user then setVisibility to invisible)

Step 2: In your setOnItemClickListener of listView add the do the following:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String idOfYourListItem =((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ids)).getText().toString();
}
```

Step 3: Now store this id for future manipulation.

Comment: I'm confused about the 'R.id.ids' part.  I have a unique identifier for each Athlete object, but this doesn't help if I can't find which Athlete from the list was selected.

Comment: R.id.ids is nothing but the id of your textView that you are going to add in your list row. In your xml if you have given the id of the textView as this `android:id="@+id/myTextView"`
Then this line should look like this: `String idOfYourListItem =((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myTextView)).getText().toString();`